# Bot Channels Registration SocketException - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, .net, azure, botframework

I have an Azure Web App with ASP.NET REST API application to behave as service for Bot Channels Registration.

In this app, I have one endpoint

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(string userToken, string botName, [FromBody] Activity activity)
```

where I receive a message from the user, process it and send back.

When I trying to communicate back to the user (either with typing activity or with an actual answer)

```
private static async Task ShowTyping(Activity activity, ConnectorClient client)
{
    var typingResponse = new Activity
    {
        Conversation = activity.Conversation,
        From = activity.Recipient,
        Locale = activity.Locale,
        Recipient = activity.From,
        ReplyToId = activity.Id,
        Id = activity.Id,
        Type = "typing"
    };
    await client.Conversations.UpdateActivityAsync(typingResponse);
}
```

...

```
foreach (var reply in replies)
{
      Trace.TraceInformation($"[{userToken}:{botName}] Sending reply {reply.Id}:{reply.Text}");
      await client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
}
```

through REST API I receive `HttpRequestException - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`:

```
2019-01-22T15:49:54  PID[17864] Error       System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)   
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)    at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.Rest.RetryDelegatingHandler.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)    at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.<UpdateActivityWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.<UpdateActivityAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at ChatFirst.Channels.BotFramework.Controllers.WebhookController.<ShowTyping>d__5.MoveNext()
```

Everything works fine on emulator and doesn't work at all in the web service.
I tried to implement REST API client by myself but got the same result.

What am I missing?

---

More information on the issue

1. I use v4.2 Bot Framework packages

   `<package id="Microsoft.Bot.Builder" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />`
     `<package id="Microsoft.Bot.Connector" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />`
     `<package id="Microsoft.Bot.Schema" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />`
2. Entire Post method, `userToken` and `botName` are my internal credentials

   ```
   /// <summary>
   ///     POST: api/v1/webhook/{userToken}/{botName}
   ///     Receive a message from a user and reply to it
   /// </summary>
   [HttpPost]
   [Route("api/v1/webhook/{userToken}/{botName}")]
   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(string userToken, string botName, [FromBody] Activity activity)
   {
       try
       {
           if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
           {
               Trace.TraceInformation($"[{userToken}:{botName}] Message from {activity.From.Id}");
               MicrosoftAppCredentials credentials = _channelGateway.GetCredentials(userToken, botName);

               if (credentials == null)
                   return Ok();

               var serviceUri = new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl);
               var client = new ConnectorClient(serviceUri, credentials);

               await ShowTyping(activity, client);

               IEnumerable<Activity> replies = await _coreTalkService.GetRepliesAsync(new BotToken(userToken, botName), activity);

               foreach (var reply in replies)
               {
                   Trace.TraceInformation($"[{userToken}:{botName}] Sending reply {reply.Id}:{reply.Text}");
                   await client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
               }
           }
           else
           {
               HandleSystemMessage(activity);
           }

           return Ok();
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           Trace.TraceError(e.ToString());
           return InternalServerError(e);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Bot Channels Registrations settings looks like this 
   [image: Settings screenshot]
4. If I reroute Bot Channel to the local instance on my dev PC through ngrok I receive the same errors.
5. I reduced entire method to perform simple echo answer, but error still remains

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(string userToken, string botName, [FromBody] Activity activity)
{
    Trace.TraceInformation($"[{userToken}:{botName}] Message from {activity.From.Id}");
    var client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl), 
        new MicrosoftAppCredentials("<secret>", "<secret>"));
    var answer = activity.CreateReply(activity.Text, activity.Locale);
    await client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(answer);
    return Ok();
}
```

6. `activity.ServiceUrl` is `https://webchat.botframework.com/`
7. Error happens if message sent through webchat, i didn't check another channels
   [image]

Comment: Hmm, well that's a pretty low level network disconnect exception you're reporting there. How are you configuring the client? Have you set up your credentials? Does this happen to the very first message being sent via the client or...?

Comment: Your Post method does not look like a normal Messaging Endpoint.  Are you bypassing the connector services and calling the bot directly?  Please share the client side code you are using to communicate with the bot.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I hope I provided enough information to clarify the problem. It should be a simple task, but I have no idea why it's not working.

Comment: You've changed the messaging endpoint signature.  The webchat control is going to call the Direct Line connector service, which will in turn call your bot's Messaging Endpoint (not sending any userToken or botName).

Comment: @EricDahlvang usetToken and botName are my internal credentials, as far as I understand for Messaging Endpoint there is no difference between `https://link/api/v1/webhook` or `https://link/api/v1/webhook/a/b`. Furthermore, I do receive user messages normally, the exception occurs when I try to reply it.

Comment: Try adding MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(activity.ServiceUrl); before sending any replies

Comment: @EricDahlvang that did not help, the error still persists. I also tried other channels, if I use Skype, `ServiceUrl` is `https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/` and the error remains.

Comment: If you provide me with an example project on GitHub, i'll set it up in my own subscription and let you know what I find out.

Comment: @EricDahlvang I uploaded sample project to https://github.com/xakpc/BotFrameworkChannel.Test
I would be grateful if you could help me to fix this problem

Comment: are the users behind NAT / corporate firewall?

Comment: There must be some conflict with one of the libraries you are referencing.  I created a new project, and it works as you expect: https://github.com/xakpc/BotFrameworkChannel.Test/pull/1

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is there must be some referenced library that is interfering with the outgoing messages in your project.

Rather than attempt to debug your project, I created a new similar project that works as expected: https://github.com/xakpc/BotFrameworkChannel.Test/pull/1

Answer (score 0):

Do you use TLS 1.2 as Security Protocol?

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53647879/3673445

*"On December 4th, 2018, the Azure Bot Service will require all connections to be secured using Transport Layer Security (TLS) 1.2. This enforcement is critical to providing the best possible security for your data. "*

Comment: System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;